# stream loop inject string only the first row

Tags: java

I try to inject a string to a list using stream, but only inject the first row.

Input:

```
1, Kelvin, 1
2, kelvin, 1
3, John, 1
```

Expected:

```
1, Kelvin, 2,  Alvin
3, John, 1, Alvin
```

Result:

```
1, Kelvin, 2 Alvin
3, John, 1, null
```

Code:

```
 String lastName = "Alvin"
    Map<Object, Person> map = list.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(
                    f -> f.getCode() + f.getName(),
                    Function.identity(),
                    (s, a) -> new Person(s.getCode(), s.getName, s.getAmount(), lastName)));
```

Comment: Of what type is `list`? Is it `List<Person>`?

Comment: @MCEmperor List<Person>

Comment: Could you show your `Person` class? Also, I cannot reproduce the result you get using the code you posted (after correcting your code to make it compilable).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you're injecting `lastName` in `mergeFunction` parameter of `Collectors.toMap` function, instead of `valueMapper` parameter.

`Collectors.toMap` takes 3 arguments:

```
Function<? super T, ? extends K> keyMapper,
Function<? super T, ? extends U> valueMapper,
BinaryOperator<U> mergeFunction
```

1. `keyMapper` will generate a key for your entry in map,
2. `valueMapper` will generate a value for your entry in map,
3. `mergeFunction` is function which is called, when the value mapping function is applied to equal element (`Object.equals()`), so both values are merged using the provided merging function.

You should provide correct mapping function as `valueMapper` argument. Provided by you `Function.identity()` will always return original input parameter:

```
Returns a function that always returns its input argument.

Type parameters:
  <T> – the type of the input and output objects to the function

Returns:
  a function that always returns its input argument

static <T> Function<T, T> identity() {
  return t -> t;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Apparently you mixed up the valueMapper and mergeFunction of the Collectors.toMap. Here is my best guess with the information given:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.function.Function;

public class Mapper {

    public class Person {
        private Integer code;
        private String name;
        private String lastName;
    
        public Person(Integer code, String name, String lastName) {
            this.code = code;
            this.name = name;
            this.lastName = lastName;
        }
    
        public Integer getCode() {
            return code;
        }
    
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
    
        public String getLastName() {
            return lastName;
        }
    
        public String toString() {
            return this.code + ", " + this.name + ", " + this.lastName;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String []args) {
        new Mapper().run();
    }
 
    public void run() {
        List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();
        persons.add(new Person(1, "Kelvin", null));
        persons.add(new Person(2, "Alvin", null));
        persons.add(new Person(3, "John", null));
    
        String lastName = "Alvin";
        Map<Object, Person> map = persons.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(
                f -> f.getCode() + f.getName(),
                p -> new Person(p.getCode(), p.getName(), lastName)));
                
        for (Map.Entry<Object, Person> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " = " + entry.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1Kelvin = 1, Kelvin, Alvin
2Alvin = 2, Alvin, Alvin
3John = 3, John, Alvin
```

Answer (score 1):

While there already are good answers I just wanted to provide my answer with a different approach to a solution.

Instead of using the valueMapper of the Collector, I used the map function of the stream with the adjustment of using a builder pattern inside of the Person pojo to aid in the usability for this.
Please note that this approach will only work if the builder pattern is used and the class itself is returned by the result of the map operation.

Run it and see it working with Ideone: https://ideone.com/WFcZCo

```
/* package whatever; // don't place package name! */

import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        List<Person> personList = new ArrayList<>();
        
        Person kelvin = new Person("1","Kelvin");
        Person alvin = new Person("2","Alvin");
        Person john = new Person("3","John");
        
        personList.add(kelvin);
        personList.add(alvin);
        personList.add(john);
        
        String lastName = "Alvin";
        Map<Object, Person> map = personList.stream()
        .map(p -> p.setLastName(lastName))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                    f -> f.getCode() + f.getName(),
                    Function.identity()
                    ));
                    
        System.out.println("Result:");
        
        for(Map.Entry<Object, Person> entry : map.entrySet()){
            Object key = entry.getKey();
            Person person = entry.getValue();
            System.out.println(person);
        }
    }
}

class Person {
    private String code;
    
    private String name;
    
    private String lastname;
    
    public Person(String code, String name){
        this.code = code;
        this.name = name;
    }
    
    public Person(String code, String name, String lastname){
        this.code = code;
        this.name = name;
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }
    
    public String getCode(){
        return code;
    }
    
    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
    
    public String getLastname(){
        return lastname;
    }

    public Person setLastName(String lastname){
        this.lastname = lastname;
        return this;
    }
    
    public String toString(){
        return code + ", " + name + ", " + lastname;
    }
}
```

And here the result:

```
Result:
1, Kelvin, Alvin
2, Alvin, Alvin
3, John, Alvin
```